# Write a string to a single cell or merged cell c#

Tags: c#, string, excel, io, merge

I am trying to write a string into a merged cell but the code will only write the first word into an unmergred cell. I tried an alternate way of attempting to write the string into a single cell then trying to merge it but that does not work either.

Is it possible to write a string into a merged cell?

```
    for (int i = 1; i < 40; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 1; j < 40; j++ )
                    {
                        if (i != 6)
                        {
                            //Puts the 2D array into excel, cell-by-cell 
                            sheet.Range[sheet.Cells[1, 1], sheet.Cells[40, 40]].Value = result;
                        }
                       //Write line 6 "Accrual Codes" to a merged cell
                        if (i == 6 && j==1)
                        {

                          sheet.Range[sheet.Cells[6, 1],sheet.Cells[6,30]].Merge();
                             Console.WriteLine(tableList[5].ToString());
                            sheet.Cells[i, 1] = tableList[5].ToString();

                        }

                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ummm.. is it me or is that code extremely redundant?

i = 1 and j = 1, Range = result. 
then
i = 1, j = 2, Range = result, again.
And so on.

Try the following:

Select the first two cells, merge them and then write a value in the first one (comment the current code)

See what happens.

If it works, something else is wrong with the code (and i think a lot can go wrong in what you've posted)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by redundant "result" is a 2d array it is writing different items into the cells. I have one specific line that i am trying to write to a merged cell (Line 6)

Comment: hm... i think the best way to make my point is to ask you this: in your code, right after "//Puts the 2D array into excel, cell-by-cell", add MessageBox.Show("here"); :)

Answer (score 0):

- When writing to a merged area in Excel, you must write to the upper
  left hand corner of the area. See this for more info:
  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7a13b963-9581-4bae-8f67-5470957c696d/write-to-merged-cell?forum=vsto.
- If you write to any cells in a merged area that aren't the upper left
  cell, you probably won't get an error but nothing will happen.
- If you want to detect the merged area to which a single cell belongs,
  use the [MergeArea](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.mergearea?view=excel-pia) property. This trivially returns the cell itself if the cell isn't merged.